# Moving /home to root partition

Tags: partitioning, root, home-directory

Im trying to move the my home to root.I copied the `/home` content to `/media/temphome` using rsync.I log into recovery mode from `grub.umount /home`.

In fstab I made an entry for `/home` using the uuid of root partition like below

```
UUID=5e63925a-300e-42a4-986e-a27203a154ea /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
UUID=5e63925a-300e-42a4-986e-a27203a154ea /home           ext4    defaults        0       2
```

`5e63925a-300e-42a4-986e-a27203a154ea` is the UUID for root partition
Reboot and log in as root in the xsession. I see it has created another home directory under `/home`. So now it's a weird `/home/home` and will mess up all the settings.

The `/home` is on the new partition alright but is it not possible at all to have this `/home/home`. Is there anything in fstab that I should add to prevent this from happening.

Thanks

Comment: Do i need to comment out the /home mount in fstab and then things will go on working the same way after i copy the existing user directories back to /home directory using rsync?

Comment: Yes, no need for the /home partition anymore. The contents of your temphome should go into the root location /home/<yourusername> if your /home was really used as a mount on that location.

Comment: Thanks ubfan1,it worked that way

Comment: You may write your own answer and after a few days, accept it, so this may be marked as solved.